# Error using sonar-activedirectory 1.0 in SonarQube 6.0

Tags: sonarqube

After upgrading to SonarQube 6.0 we cannot use the SSO login plugin anymore. This is our SonarQube.log in TRACE mode:

```
DEBUG web[o.s.s.u.NewUserNotifier] User created: xxxx@xxxx. Notifying NewUserHandler handlers...
TRACE web[sql] time=0ms | sql=select u.login,u.name,u.email,u.active,u.scm_accounts,u.created_at,u.updated_at from users u  where u.updated_at>? | params=1470426045520
TRACE web[es] ES refresh request on indices 'users' | time=94ms
**ERROR web[rails] cannot load Java class org.sonar.server.user.RubyUserSession**
DEBUG web[http] GET /active_directory/validate | time=2703ms
```

The plugin configuration is very simple (just one line):

```
sonar.security.realm=ACTIVE_DIRECTORY
```

Is there a way to solve this problem by adding other configuration settings and how can I tell if this error is in the SonarQube or SSO code?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm running into the same thing.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-activedirectory/issues/9) issue. The plugin must be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks. I wrote the linked google group note. Sadly it looks like SSO as it worked isn't going to be supported even if the plugin is updated. Users will still have to click a link.

https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-activedirectory/issues/9

Use the BaseIdentityProvider API (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/server/authentication/BaseIdentityProvider.java) -> **It will allow SSO by creating a link in the login page**

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the authentication interface is changed in SonarQube 6.0 in order to phasing out some old software components. So it cannot be solved by changing the SonarQube configuration; the SSO plugin must be updated. A ticket can be found on [SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-activedirectory GitHub](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-activedirectory) and in the [SonarQube Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/4I3Im60SfkY).